# Jquery HTML CSS Slider issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use the demo from this site : http://slidesjs.com/#overview
and try to implement two slider on a page. I am customizing the Linking demo.
As i am using two different slider : slider1 and slider2 with different css
so I used global.css for slider-1 and created text.css for slider-2.

I noticed that the `js: slides.min.jquery.js` file uses the `css` element for classes like 
`slides_container`, `next`, `prev` . So i created another `js :slider.text.jquery.js` 
replacing the css content by: `slides_containerT`, `nextT`, `prevT` as per `text.css`. 
but the code is not working. please help me as my project is due next monday.

Could you please suggest how I can modify the `slides.min.jquery.js` so that it 
takes both `global`.css and `text.css` elements to create pagination.

Cheers,
Pam

Answer (score 3):

You can define multiple slides in one page no need to create `slider.text.jquery.js` file like you created.
and make your 2nd slider styles according to `#slider2`.

```
$(function(){
    $('#slider1').slides({
        generateNextPrev: true,
        play: 2500
    });
    $('#slider2').slides({
        generateNextPrev: true,
        play: 4500
    });
});
```